# After parsing xml files in perl, getting special characters

Tags: xml, perl

I'm parsing a xml file & storing it in Database [using perl]. At the time of parsing am getting special characters like - &[quot;amp;lt;gt;].
What is the meaning of these special characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here on wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 2):

Those are html-safe / xml-safe translations of characters that wouldn't be legal embedded within the document in their bare form.  >"&< are all 'special characters', with special meaning in the context of HTML and XML.  Well... technically > isn't reserved, but the others are.  `&amp;` is a 'safe' way of specifying an ampersand character without throwing grit into the gears of the XML or HTML parser.

HTML::Entities is a module that helps you to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HTML::Entities` module if you want to get their literal value (the way the HTML displays them).

For more info about entities, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) and [this](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html)